# How to match ascii to non ascii using regex expressions?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string variables

```
string1 = "cafe ceramique"
string2 = "Café Céramique"
```

I want a regular expression that matches string1 to string2.

In a more generic way, how can I match any string ascii string to a non ascii one with regular expresions?

Comment: What did you try so far? Do you have a [mcve] we can help you with?

Comment: If you want to make a regex that finds these instances, you could make it like [cC]af[eé] [cC][eé]ramique. You explain to regex you could have either caps or lower c and e or é, of course you could make it more universal to more text, but this is an exact answer to match your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
import unicodedata
string1 == unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', string2).encode('ASCII', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
```

In your example the first letters of the words were in different case. Do you want to match case-insensitively?

Comment: Had forgotton to add `decode` .The comparison would stiill return false because string1 is lower case and string2 has uppercase 'C' but works as intended.

Comment: I like your solution. just add `.lower()` and I think it's exactly what OP asked, unless he's forced to use a regex. anyway I'll upvote your answer

Answer (score 0):

You could use character classes and the case insensitive modifier:

```
rx = r'caf[eé]\ c[eé]ramique'
```

In `Python`, the complete example would look like:

```
import re
string = """cafe ceramique
Café Céramique"""
rx = r'caf[eé]\ c[eé]ramique'
matches = re.findall(rx,string,re.IGNORECASE)
```

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/aV1uX3/1).
In general, `e` is a completely other character than `é`, `è` or `ê` considering [the ASCII representation](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: This only works for the given example and for non-ascii text in general.

Comment: @RSingh: Most regular expressions only work for a subset of given input strings...